# How to display google maps code in smarty

Tags: html, google-maps, iframe, smarty

```
<div>
    {$google_map_link}
</div>
```

I am assigning the following google map iframe codes into smarty and trying to display map on the screen.

google map that assigned to smarty variable `{$google_map_link}` is

```
<iframe width="300" height="300" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.co.in/maps?q=Tiriyos&amp;gl=in&amp;hl=en&amp;sll=13.008237,80.193329&amp;sspn=0.206059,0.363579&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;view=map&amp;cid=5721197682818793762&amp;hq=Tiriyos&amp;hnear=&amp;ll=12.948405,80.137217&amp;spn=0.006441,0.011362&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
<br />
<small>
    <a href="http://maps.google.co.in/maps?q=Tiriyos&gl=in&hl=en&sll=13.008237,80.193329&sspn=0.206059,0.363579&ie=UTF8&view=map&cid=5721197682818793762&hq=Tiriyos&hnear=&ll=12.948405,80.137217&spn=0.006441,0.011362&z=17" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a>
</small>
```

***I expect to display the google map on screen but only iframe codes are displayed***

How to solve this...

Comment: Looks like iframe should load fine: http://jsfiddle.net/zpczQ/. I'm guessing that something is wrong with the string you are assigning to `google_map_link`. Could you please include the exact PHP code? You might also take a look at what the iframe looks like in a browser's source to see any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php

```
<?
$google_map_link = html_entity_decode($google_map_code);
$smarty->assign('google_map_link', $google_map_link);
?>
```

In HTML

```
<div>
    {$google_map_link}
</div>
```

I had used `html_entity_decode` to decode google maps iframe code and displayed in smarty. This is easiest way to display google maps in smarty.

I may help some one else

Answer (score 1):

I've tried your code and it works on Smarty 3.0.8.

Why don't you use Google maps API (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html)?
I usualy put html into the template and just pass the values. Example below:

php:

```
<?php
$smarty->assign('google_map_x', '12.948405');
$smarty->assign('google_map_y', '80.137217');
?>
```

template:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng({$google_map_x}, {$google_map_y});
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng, 
    map: map, 
    title:"Tiriyos"
  }); 
}
</script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:300px;height:300px"></div>
```

Then you can put your info window on your marker. Read more here: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#InfoWindows